# Drop packet with libpcap

Tags: packet, libpcap

Is it possible to have libpcap remove a packet instead of just sniff it as it passes through?  I'm wanting to intercept each packet and encapsulate it into a new packet along with measurement data, but both packets (mine and the original) both reach the destination.

Comment: since this question is about libcap, you might want to add a libpcap tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You need to write a driver (for your operating system) to make the networking stack filter out packets.

Comment: There are many linux kernel options to change the behavior of the network stack. For example, `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` turns off forwarding of packets that aren't addressed to this host.

Comment: @Ben: that's correct. However, I doubt that you can use such a configuration to implement what he wants.

Comment: Linux kernel's IPTables is a good place for digging info about dropping pcakets

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could do this is by being the only physical path between the sender and receiver and turning off packet forwarding on the interceptor.

If you're capturing wireless traffic, there's nothing you can do. No software library can remove radio waves from the ambient air.

Answer (score 1):

No, libpcap cannot "remove a packet".

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve, but it looks like you want to receive data, add some additional information to it, and republish it. If you are working with a datagram protocol such as UDP, then you might be able to simply resend your augmented data to a different UDP port.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Ben S, you can't remove packets off the air, but you can stop them reaching their destination - using ARP cache poisoning etc.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you can not use libpcap. libpcap is a passive listener. If you are on Linux, you can use a netfilter, which hooks into iptables.  Here is an example of how to do that.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7184