# Drop captured packet

Tags: c, linux, libpcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

The project I am working has the requirement of dropping captured packets. I am successfully captuing packets with the use of `libpcap` like so,

```
pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, NULL);
```

Where in the callback function I capture the given number of packets in the num_packets argument. My requirement is to drop the captured packets.

I tried checking for help and ended up empty handed. Any reference of code snippets to perform this requirement of dropping captured packets via `libpcap` is much appreciated. :)

---

**EDIT**
Alternative suggestions are welcome if this is not possible via `libpcap`.

NOTE that before dropping the packet I need to obtain the `destination/ source ip address` and `payload` of the packet to be dropped.

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/1284759/1741542

Comment: @OlafDietsche thank you for your comment :) Thats rough luck..we have to come up with out own mechanism isnt it. are there any libraries that could perform this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if there's a library. [Libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is for network packet capture only, AFAIK.

From my limited knowledge, I would say dropping a packet is just ignoring or not forwarding it. However this is not done in some program, but the kernel's network stack.

You can accomplish this, by defining appropriate rules in [netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org/). There, you will also find [libnftnl](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnftnl/index.html), which allows to communicate with the Linux netfilter subsystem. But as I read it, you can only define rules and not drop individual packets.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response..I will check on what you have told :)

Comment: "Libpcap is for network packet capture only, AFAIK."  You are 100% correct.  "I would say dropping a packet is just ignoring or not forwarding it. However this is not done in some program, but the kernel's network stack."  Yes.  The way to do that depends on the OS; the question is tagged with "linux", so they're presumably running Linux.  I think there are ways of tapping into the stack so that user-mode code can decide what packets to drop or not (rather than having to supply rules to the kernel).